# Delete all lines that have a specific word in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Using Pycharm, I want to delete all lines that have a specific word. Does someone know how we can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use replace feature with regex (e.g. `^.*hello.*$\n`) to match the whole line (and `\n`) containing a word and replace it with nothing:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Search the particular word (Ctrl+F) and Ctrl+Alt+Shift+J select the whole line using arrow then delete.

[image]